# Electric current through the resistor of an AC $(L)RC$-circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, complex-numbers

I have a question regarding more complex circuits.

For the sake of simplicity, suppose we have an AC source with an alternating voltage $U=U_0\cos{(\omega t)}$ and the angular frequency $\omega$ tied in parallel in a circuit with a resistor of resistance $R$ and a capacitor $C$. The impedance of the resistor is $R$ and that of the capacitor is $\frac{1}{i\omega C}$.

[image]

We can draw a complex pointer diagram showcasing the currents and the potential difference. The total current of the circuit is $\sqrt{I_R^2+I_C^2} \ ,$ where $I_R=\frac{U_0}{R}$ and $I_C=U_0\omega C$. $U_0$ is real and the same for all elements because of the parallel circuit.

[image]

Which current flows through $R$? Is it $I_R$ or $I_0$? Is the current through the resistor really always in phase with $U$? What power will the resistor really dissipate:

$$\frac{I_0^2}{2R} \ \ \ or \ \ \ \frac{I_R^2}{2R} \ ?$$

Is the "current" through the capacitor always $\frac{\pi}{2}$ behind $U$ or can it be in phase with $U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the current through the resistor really always in phase with ?

Ideally, yes.

> What power will the resistor really dissipate?

The power associated with the current through the resistor alone.

> Is the "current" through the capacitor always /2 behind  or can it be in phase with ?

The current through an ideal capacitor *leads* the voltage across it by /2. Always. I don't know why you put current in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one more thing, the current through the resistor is always $\frac{U}{R}$ or is it $I_0$?

Comment: I0 is the (complex) *sum* of the currents through the resistor and capacitor.

Comment: Yeah this makes the most sense, thanks!